# why after running abouts.us page it is showing url not found?

Tags: pycharm

## Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

127.0.0.1 - - [18/Mar/2024 12:29:42] "GET /aboutus HTTP/1.1" 404 -

127.0.0.1 - - [18/Mar/2024 12:32:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

127.0.0.1 - - [18/Mar/2024 12:32:22] "GET /static/images/1.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -

127.0.0.1 - - [18/Mar/2024 12:32:22] "GET /static/images/2.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -

127.0.0.1 - - [18/Mar/2024 12:32:22] "GET /static/images/3.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -

127.0.0.1 - - [18/Mar/2024 12:32:24] "GET /aboutus HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: Why *should* it be found?